# how to send async http post - ios

Tags: ios, http, post, nsurlconnection

I have a little problem with my app. I want to send some http request asynchronously to server. I create this method:

```
- (void)sendHTTPRequest:(NSString *)urlString type:(NSString *)type idNegozio:(NSNumber *)idNegozio {

    self.negozi = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSData *jsonData;
    NSString *jsonString;

    if ([type isEqualToString:@"shops"]) {

        self.reqNeg = YES;
        self.reqApp = NO;
```

...

```
    jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:0 error:nil];
    jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



    else if ([type isEqualToString:@"appointments"])
    {
        [self.loadingIconApp startAnimating];

        self.reqNeg = NO;
        self.reqApp = YES;
```

...

```
            jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:0 error:nil];
            jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:urlString];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:30];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody: jsonData];

    NSURLConnection * conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];

    [conn start];
```

}

and I use this methods for connection:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    self.responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
                  willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
    return nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    if (self.reqNeg == YES) {
        //here use the responseData for my first http request
    }

    if (self.reqApp == YES) {

        //here use the responseData for second http request
    }


}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

}
```

but in this way only the first connection works and I can use the responseData. While, If I try to send other http request the method connectionDidFinishLoading doesn't work and other methods too.
Anyone have an idea??

Comment: Your conn object is just a local variable, you should make it a member variable of a class. Are you trying to send things simultaneously? Use a separate NSURLConnection for each thing that is being sent at the same time, or else use one but only send things one after the other. With your code if you call sendHTTPRequest more than once before the first send has finished you're going to overwrite the previous NSURLConnection object with a new one each time

Comment: I already send request only one after the other. And I am sure that the first request finishes with success. But the second request seems that don't start

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the async request one by one you can do that:

```
- (void)request1 {
  NSString *requestString = @"your url here";
  NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
  [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: requestString]]
                                     queue:queue
                         completionHandler:
   ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
     NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
     if (!error && httpResponse.statusCode >= 200 && httpResponse.statusCode <300) {
        // call the request2 here which is similar to request 1
        // your request2 method here
    }
  }];
}
```

hope this help you~ thank you~

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good to me.  Here are my ideas:

Are you sure your second NSURLConnection is being created and sent out?
Maybe it's never being sent.

Are you calling your sendHTTPRequest:type:idNegozio: method with a different type while your second connection is still sent out?
You don't have a check at the beginning of the send function to make sure you're not already sending out a connection.  Maybe your flags are being switched mid-connection.

The if statements in your didFinish method should probably be combined with an else.  Just in case you wanted to fire off an 'app' connection after handling a 'neg' connection you don't accidentally fall through and try to handle the response twice.

Also, you don't have to explicitly call 'start' on an NSURLConnection unless you pass NO to the startImmediately: parameter in the constructor.  That shouldn't cause a problem though.

Comment: thank you for the help, I understand that the connection doesn't start because there is  this error: Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL"